# iOS Core data Many-to-Many relationship difference between addRelationshipObject and addRelationship?

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many

Currently, I am creating an application which uses core data as local storage. I have questions on two entities of my application: artists and albums. One artist can produce many albums while one album can consist of several artists as well.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Albums;

@interface Artists : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *toAlbums;
@end

@interface Artists (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addToAlbumsObject:(Albums *)value;
- (void)removeToAlbumsObject:(Albums *)value;
- (void)addToAlbums:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeToAlbums:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

What is the difference between addToAlbumsObject:(Albums *)value & addToAlbums:(NSSet *)values?

if I want to insert some information to Artists and Albums, for example, Artist "Jame" and "Jonh" produces 2 albums "sky album" and "star album", and "sky album". Here is the code that I did.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

Artists *artists = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Artists" inManagedObjectContext:context];

artists.name = @"Jame";

Albums *albums = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Albums" inManagedObjectContext:context];

albums.name = @"sky album";
```

What should I do next in order to store the information I wanted. 
Thanks in advance for all comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addToAlbumsObject:` adds a *single* Album object to the `toAlbums` relationship of the Artist,
e.g.

```
Artists *anArtist = ...;
Albums *anAlbum = ...;
[anArtist addToAlbumsObject:anAlbum];
```

establishes the relationship between `anArtist` and `anAlbum`.

`addToAlbums:` adds *multiple* Album objects to the `toAlbums` relationship in a single step:

```
Artists *anArtist = ...;
Albums *album1 = ...;
Albums *album2 = ...;
NSSet *setOfAlbums = [NSSet setWithObjects:album1, album2, nil];
[anArtist addToAlbums:setOfAlbums];
```

This is (I think) less often used, because you can achieve the same with calling 
`addToAlbumsObject:` for each album separately.

Perhaps everything becomes slightly less confusing if you use the *singular* form for your entity names (Album, Artist) and rename the relationship from `toAlbums` to `albums`.
Then the first code block becomes:

```
Artist *anArtist = ...;
Album *anAlbum = ...;
[anArtist addAlbumsObject:anAlbum];
```

Comment: Highly Appreciated for your answer. But do I need to add a reverse like,

[anAlbum addToArtistsObject:anArtist];

Comment: @user2756388: No. If `toAlbums` and `toArtists` are defined as *inverse relationships* then setting one direction is sufficient and automatically sets the other direction.

Comment: @user2756388: You are welcome. - Note that you can "accept" an answer by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as solved, and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer.

Comment: oh I just know about it.

Comment: I follow what u told me and save it using 
if([context save:&error]) NSLog(@"Save successful");

I saw the message save successful, but there is no data in my .sqlite file.
Please help!

Comment: @user2756388: That seems to be a separate problem, so may I suggest that you start a new question? Then more people will see it and can perhaps answer.